# AspCore application secured by Azure AD is trapped in an infinite authentication redirect loop

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

In a MVC Core Web Application targeting Full .Net Framework, Azure AD is used for authentication. A controller action is referenced in an IFrame inside Dynamics 365 (same AD Tenant). In Chrome and Firefox the iFrame is trapped in an infinite redirect loop.

In Edge Browser the behaviour is as expected. After authentication the page is displayed correctly. The request trace is as follows:

- GET https://server/page -> 302 to login.microsoftonline.com
- GET https://login.microsoftonline.com -> 200 with redirect form
- POST https://server/signin-oidc -> 302 to https://server/page
- GET https://server/page -> 200

In Google Chrome and Firefox it ends up in an infinite redirect loop and the request trace is like this:

- GET https://server/page -> 302 to login.microsoftonline.com
- GET https://login.microsoftonline.com -> 200 with redirect form
- POST https://server/signin-oidc -> 302 to https://server/page
- GET https://server/page -> 302 to login.microsoftonline.com
- GET https://login.microsoftonline.com -> 200 with redirect form
- POST https://server/signin-oidc -> 302 to https://server/page
- GET https://server/page -> 302 to login.microsoftonline.com
- GET https://login.microsoftonline.com -> 200 with redirect form
- POST https://server/signin-oidc -> 302 to https://server/page
- GET https://server/page -> 302 to login.microsoftonline.com
- GET https://login.microsoftonline.com -> 200 with redirect form
- POST https://server/signin-oidc -> 302 to https://server/page

and so fourth...

Closing Browsers, Clearing caches or using in-private mode did not help.

The application uses the stable release of Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages in version 2.1.1.

Code in Startup.cs is unchanged as it is setup by Visual Studio Web App project template for organizational accounts.

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();
```

Comment: Need to see config otherwise we are blind... Cause what you posted doesn't help.  `Startup.cs` to start and of course you place `xxxxx` in place of keys and ids

Comment: Added Auth Code from Startup.cs.

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem